# How to interpret feature importance for ensemble methods?

Tags: machine-learning, python, random-forest, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

I'm using ensemble methods (random forest, xgbclassifier, etc) for classification.

One important aspect is feature importance prediction, which is like below:

```
           Importance
Feature-A   0.25
Feature-B   0.09
Feature-C   0.08
.......
```

This model achieves accuracy score around 0.85; obviously Feature-A is dominantly important, so I decided to remove Feature-A and calculated again.

However, after removing Feature-A, I still found a good performance with accuracy around 0.79.

This doesn't make sense to me, because Feature-A contributes 25% for the model, if removed, why accuracy score is barely affected?

I know ensemble methods hold an advantage to combine 'weak' features into 'strong' ones, so accuracy score mostly relies on aggregation and less sensitive to important feature removal?

======================================

One similar question would be:
if I used first 100 features to achieve accuracy score 0.8;
and used second 100 features to achieve accuracy score 0.9;

So if now combined these 200, what would be expected accuracy score? Simply 0.85?

Thanks

Comment: Feature importance should (IMO) really be called something like "model participation", it measures how often and how much a feature was used in the model (in most cases, to make a split in a tree).  If you remove a feature, the model may make up for it's absence by finding other remaining features that hold some of the same distinguishing information, i.e. features that are correlated with the feature you removed.  This is a fundamental aspect of multi-feature models.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/276028/2921, https://stackoverflow.com/q/43637662/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: See also the [help/on-topic] which says "Please note, however, that cross-posting is not encouraged on SE sites. Choose one best location to post your question. Later, if it proves better suited on another site, it can be migrated." ... please consider removing one of your posts (I suggest this one)